# how can I re-execute my Python program by clicking a button

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program I am editing endlessly and each time I make a change, I have to exit and restart again.  I would like to be able to reload and restart without having to exit and come back in again.

Here is a simple program in a file called reload.py that would do what I want if there was something like reexec available:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def do_load(self):
        print("time to reload")
        reexec("reload.py")

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.my_reload = Button(self)
        self.my_reload["text"] = "Reload",
        self.my_reload["command"] = self.do_load
        self.my_reload.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

I experimented with using reload of just the Application class with:

```
def do_load(self):
    print("time to reload")
    reload(Application)
```

and I get an error:

```
File "python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 122, in reload
    raise TypeError("reload() argument must be module")
TypeError: reload() argument must be module
```

It this an RTFM case where I need to learn more about modules?

Any help or suggestions will be gladly accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use `importlib` here you should have to reload the main module, and kill the TK instance, so python would succeed to recreate another one, with the edited source code.

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, on_reload=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.my_reload = Button(self)
        self.my_reload["text"] = "Reload",
        self.my_reload["command"] = on_reload
        self.my_reload.pack()
```

**executor.py**

```
import tkinter
import importlib
import main


class Executor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.app = main.Application(master=self.root, on_reload=self.on_reload)
        self.app.mainloop()

    def on_reload(self):
        self.root.destroy()

        importlib.reload(main)

        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.app = main.Application(master=self.root, on_reload=self.on_reload)
        self.app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Executor()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just finished solving this exact problem for a work project I was creating. The answer Gal Ben David provided does work, but only for applications with a single window. This is because the `tkinter.Tk` root is created upon initialization of the application and not under the condition statement at the bottom of the script. So props to user1683793 for putting it in the right place. As long as `root` is a global variable, you can easily use it to spawn other windows with the same root object.

Take the following project root directory as an example.

```
    root/
     ├── __main__.py
     └── myapp/
          ├── __init__.py
          ├── core.py
          ├── datatypes.py
          └── gui.py
```

Ignoring the `__init__.py` file of the `myapp` package, you have two modules that house 
your application's user interface: the `myapp.core` module that holds the main window, and the `myapp.gui` module that holds all components used by the core container. Seeing as how changing a class means changing the module itself, it makes more sense to reload the entire module so an up-to-date version is always being used at runtime.

To reload the application GUI without restarting the program, the process used must:

1. Reload the edited module (typically using `importlib.reload`)
2. Build new objects from new module's contents using information from the old objects.

   - Be sure to transfer ownership of any additional objects/attributes to the new objects.
3. Dereference the old objects for garbage collection. This includes the old module as well as all classes and functions related to it.

**root/myapp/core.py**

First, you need a container class that's completely isolated from the rest of your GUI components. Preferably starting in and able to return to an empty default state, this is what will remain when you attempt to reload its components after editing `root/myapp/gui.py`. This default state will retain only the menu bar, where all reload commands are stored inside the Runtime menu.

```
from tkinter import *

#Import commented out until live editing has been completed
#from myapp import gui, datatypes

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master=master)

        self.build_vars() #Builds all Tk variables used by this frame
        self.build_menus() #Builds Application Menus

        self.container = Frame(self) #Container for all Application Components 
        self.build_components()  #Builds GUI Components
        ...

    def build_menus(self):
        """
        Builds the application menus bar.
        """
        self.menubar = Menu(self) #Menu Bar

        filemenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0) #File Menu
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu) #Adds File Menu to Menu Bar

        runtimemenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0) #Runtime Menu - Location of All 
        runtimemenu.add_command(label="Reload Window", command=self.reload_window)
        runtimemenu.add_command(label="Reload Components", command=self.reload_components)
        runtimemenu.add_separator()
        runtimemenu.add_command(label="Reload Datatypes", command=self.reload_datatypes)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Runtime", menu=runtimemenu)

        self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)

    def build_components(self):
        """
        Builds the application components.
        """
        #Keep all imports to reloadable dependencies in 
        #the local scope to use the most recent version
        from myapp.gui import AppFrame

        self.pane = AppFrame(self.container)
        self.pane.pack()
        ...
        self.container.pack()

    def build_vars(self):
        """
        Build all Tk variables (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar) used by the application.
        """
        ...

    def reload_window(self):
        """
        Reloads the entire Application frame.

        Use when making minor changes to this class to update the Application instance at runtime.
        """
        from myapp import core
        from importlib import reload
        core = reload(core) #Reload the current module to reflect any changes
        cls = getattr(app, type(self).__name__) #Get Application from reloaded module
        frame = cls(self.master)
        self.destroy() #Destroy instance of the old application before packing the new instance
        frame.pack()

    def reload_components(self):
        """
        Reloads all components used in the Application frame.

        Use when making changes to the classes of GUI components to 
        update the application GUI at runtime.
        """
        from myapp import gui
        from importlib import reload
        reload(gui) #Reload the current module to reflect any changes
        #Destroy the old GUI Components
        for widget in self.container.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        self.build_components() #Rebuild the GUI components using the reloaded module

    def reload_datatypes(self):
        """
        Reloads a user module named `datatypes` .

        This command is useful for reflecting major and 
        minor changes to the target module at runtime.
        """
        from myapp import datatypes
        from importlib import reload
        reload(datatypes)
```

The `reload_window` and `reload_components` methods reload the core and component modules of the application respectively.

`reload_window` then searches the reloaded `myapp.core` for a class with the same name as the current application class, creates a new object from the new class, and destroys the old application window.

`reload_components` removes all components from the underlying container, then reruns `build_components`. Because the import statement is declared from within `build_components`, it will always use the most recent version of the reloaded module.

**root/myapp/gui.py**

This module will contain all GUI components used by the `myapp.core` module.

```
from tkinter import *

class AppFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master=master)
        ...
```

**root/__main__.py**

Finally, with `__main__.py` at the top of your directory, you can run your application and reload specific parts of it without having to restart the program entirely. The only piece of user code explicitly referenced is `myapp.core.Application` on startup.

```
from tkinter import Tk
#Module Setup Code
...

def create_application(master):
    #Keep all imports to reloadable dependencies in 
    #the local scope to use the most recent version
    from myapp.core import Application
    return Application(master=root)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = create_application(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Note: For this to work as efficiently as possible, you should keep any imports to reloaded modules localized to the functions that use them until you are finished editing those modules. Depending on the loader you use, reloading modules this way multiple times can leave multiple versions of the same module lingering throughout your program if imported globally. When imported locally, no active reference to the module is retained aside from the one in `sys.modules`. Any unreferenced modules replaced during the reload will then be available for garbage collection.

In the event that this isn't possible for you, one workaround would be to include a function `force_update(self, module)` that searches for references to content from old module versions and creates a new object using references mapped to the most recent version of the module. Finding the old module isn't even necessary for this. Checking if a function is up to date can be as simple as the following.

```
def force_update(self, module):
    func = self.attr_func
    same = func.__module__ == module.__name__
    newfunc = getattr(module, func.__name__)
    if same and func != newfunc:
        self.attr_func = newfunc
    return self
```